# How to integrate $\int\frac1{1+2x}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

What approach would be ideal in finding the solution to the integration problem $\int\frac1{1+2x}dx$?

Comment: Consider $u=2x+1,du=2xdx$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice

$$ d(1 + 2x) = 2 dx $$. Hence

$$ \int \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{d(1+2x)}{1+2x} = \frac{1}{2} \ln(1 + 2x) + C$$

In general, if $a,b$ are a real numbers.

$$ \int \frac{ dx}{ a + bx} = \frac{1}{b} \ln(a + bx) + C $$

you should verify this.

Comment: I like this response personally since it highlights that you can derive with respect to an expression as opposed to having to use a macro u = 1 + 2x and that the derivative is really a 2 argument operator: what you are deriving and with respect to what

Answer (score 1):

In general
\begin{align}
\int\frac{a}{bx+c}dx=\frac{a}{b}\ln (bx+c)+C
\end{align}
**Proof:**

Let $u=bx+c$ then $x=\cfrac{u-c}{b}$ and $dx=\cfrac{du}{b}$. Hence
\begin{align}
\int\frac{a}{bx+c}dx=\int\frac{a}{u}\cdot\frac{du}{b}=\frac{a}{b}\int\frac{du}{u}=\frac{a}{b}\ln u+C=\frac{a}{b}\ln (bx+c)+C
\end{align}